# ReactiveCocoa: throttle the other way around

Tags: reactive-cocoa

When the user is typing in a textview I want to send a "typing" message to a remote server. I can't really figure out how I would throttle this "start first then wait"-style with ReactiveCocoa. Please note that I'm an absolute RAC beginner so I hope I'm not asking any obvious :)

So, my problem is that with something like this:

```
[[self.textInputbar.textView.rac_textSignal throttle:4] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    // Send "typing" message to the server here
}];
```

It sends the typing message *after* the user stopped typing. What I really need it that it sends the message immediately, then throttles, sends it again after 4 seconds if the user is still typing, etc. So it has to work the other way around as what throttle actually does.

Comment: `-throttle:` doesn't really work the way most users actually want. It looks like this will be addressed in the Swift version of ReactiveCocoa, but in the meantime, there's a GitHub issue in which a ReactiveCocoa user has contributed a good Obj-C solution at https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1396